# Which mobile game featuring a red-roof cartoon house is this?

Tags: android, game-identification

[image: a red cartoon house on a mobile screen]

This is a screenshot has taken from a YouTube mobile review video where reviewer is playing a game.

Graphics of this game looks nice. What is the name of the game?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It looks like the game is called Rescue Wings ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playstack.rescuewings&hl=en_US) and [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/rescue-wings/id1444883925)). I discovered this by cropping screenshot to get just the house, which lead me to the [developers website](https://www.littlechicken.nl/game/rescuewings/).

[image: Rescue Wings house]